# disabling touch screen in old windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, touchscreen

I have an old computer that runs on Windows XP. The computer is designed to be connected with some specialised sensor. It has a touch screen built into the box, which is supposed to make life easier. I can't replace the computer as it has built-in cards for data acquisition purposes and these cards are not on the market anymore.

The problem is that the touch screen is gone. After switching the comp on, a mouse pointer jumps all over the screen and makes it impossible to use, even with an external keyboard connected.

I can't find a way to disable the touch screen and run only on the external keyboard.

The computer does not fit any normal specification or make. It is very specialised and when I opened it does not even have the board's names printed on it.

I can access BIOS and I can disable LVDS display and run only on VGA but in general, I need LVDS screen to see it.

Where should I look for the touch screen option or is it any sensible way to disconnect it inside?

Comment: It it very likely that the touchscreen interface runs via a driver, and drivers can be disabled, and the device will no longer be able to communicate.  If you can get partial input control,  As long as you do not disable your last control interface , and had nothing to lose, locate the device in the device manager, and disable it.  or flat out delete it, which will still stop it, and it is likely to re-install on boot.  Do you even have that much control?

Comment: Simplest way would be to make sure the device is removed from the list of devices Windows can detect and make sure no driver is supported.  Booting into Safe Mode should allow you to do this.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to keep this machine in operation, and it is for a business, then you need to take it to a computer repair shop and allow them to return the machine to functionality (according to your parameters)... and then you need to accept the expense as necessary to keep the machine in operation.  You would have the business pay for it, and write it off on your taxes.

If you are unable to identify this machine, and more specifically if you are unable to **provide us with details that would identify this machine**, then how can you expect any of us to be able to assist you?

[Windows XP had a Tablet edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP_editions#Tablet_PC_Edition) but you haven't mentioned whether or not the computer is running this edition of Windows.  For all we know, you could be running Windows XP Pro, with proprietary software handling the touch screen.  So, it is possible that your answer could be to simply disable that software.  Or, if you were running Windows XP Tablet PC Edition, you could try wiping it and installing just a standard version of XP, thus ignoring any and all Touch Screen aspects of the OS.

Your reference to LVDS is odd... have you actually tried replacing the touch screen monitor with a regular one?  you say "in general" when you refer to the whole thing.  We would need **specific** details as to what you have done, not general information.

Just because the special cards you have in that machine are not on the market anymore, this doesn't mean that you can't find any hardware drivers for them... but again, you would need to identify them to do so.  This is where taking the computer to a qualified professional comes in.  You don't seem to be quite... qualified for the task before you.  No insult intended, I am only basing that statement on the missing information in your question, and the assumption that this is a business machine needed for business reasons, but you are not approaching this from a business standpoint in a professional manner.